# Grouping and aggregating using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This was inspired by [Aggregate loans report without using Python standard aggregate or group functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/173675/24208) question, but I've decided to approach it using `pandas`.

To recap, sample input:

```
MSISDN,Network,Date,Product,Amount
1,Network 1,12-Mar-2016,Loan Product 1,1000
2,Network 2,16-Mar-2016,Loan Product 1,1122
3,Network 3,17-Mar-2016,Loan Product 2,2084
4,Network 3,18-Mar-2016,Loan Product 2,3098
5,Network 2,01-Apr-2016,Loan Product 1,5671
```

Desired output:

```
Network,Product,Month\Year,Currency,Count
Network 1,Loan Product 1,03-16,1000,1
Network 2,Loan Product 1,03-16,1122,1
Network 2,Loan Product 1,04-16,5671,1
Network 3,Loan Product 2,03-16,5182,2
```

In other words, the task is to group the data from the `input.csv` file by `Network`, `Product` and `month+year` of the `Date` column, then calculate the sum of `Currency` column keeping track of counts in each group.

I've solved it via creating a separate `Month\Year` column first, loading the `Date` values into `datetime` objects and dumping into a `month-year` format, then grouping by the desired columns using `.groupby()` and then aggregating with `sum` and `count` with further renaming the columns to the desired column names:

```
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df['Month\Year'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, "%d-%b-%Y").strftime('%m-%y'))

grouped = df.groupby(['Network', 'Product', 'Month\Year'])['Amount']

df = grouped.agg(['sum', 'count']).rename(columns={'sum': 'Currency', 'count': 'Count'}).reset_index()
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Is this the most optimal and readable `pandas`-based solution? Can it be further improved?

I am particularly not quite happy with renaming columns after aggregation - there should be a more straightforward way to aggregate into the custom-named columns.

Comment: If the `Date` column is a `datetime` you could skip the new column added and use [`Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html), but that leaves you with `datetime` objects instead of `str`s. I don't really know a way to avoid the renaming at the end

Comment: if the `Date` is not a `datetime`, you can use `pd.to_datetime()` instead of the `lambda` and `strptime`